# Getting parse errors when building insert queries in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

new to PDO (version php-pdo-5.3.5-1.el5) and running into the following error when trying to use PDO for a MySQL insert:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ';' in /var/www/appdb/test.php on line 3
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
<?php
  $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=appdb", sqladmin, password);
  $STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO appdb ( id ) values ( default )");
  $STH->execute();
?>
```

I have been on google for an hour trying to figure this out and have not been able to determine what could be causing this error.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that's exactly your code?

Comment: Is the code we are looking at here the complete contents of `/var/www/appdb/test.php`? What is in `/var/www/appdb/test.php` at line 3? Because there are no syntax errors in the code posted here...

Comment: @phil - For the most part, I copied it from the file, but the only thing I edited was dbname and password on line 2.

Comment: @DaveRandom - You are looking at the complete file, line three literally being line three of the code (containing the prepare statement).

Comment: @somecallmemike I've edited my answer with what I believe is the real problem

Comment: In that case, that is the oddest parse error I have ever seen. There is nothing syntactically wrong with it. Try wrapping line 3 in an `if () `, or do `or die()` or something, so it still executes but use different syntax, and see if you still get the same error.

Comment: The code above, as it is, parses. I copy-pasted it into a file, and `php -l`ed it against 4.3.10, 5.2.17 and 5.3.6 and none of them had any problems with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=appdb", sqladmin, password);
```

should probably be

```
$DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=appdb", $sqladmin, $password);
```

unless you have somewhere `define('sqladmin','something');` and `define('password','something');`

Comment: It is, but for the purposes of this example I put in junk data.

Comment: Why do people put junk as their example so we have no way of knowing what is "example junk" and what is a legit error?

Comment: @somecallmemike No, no, no! If your original code uses strings, we need to see your question as it appears in code.

Comment: @Phil - I actually updated the code to reflect this as well.  You were correct that the username and password strings were breaking the dbh connection.  I re-edited my comment to reflect the original problem.  Sorry for being such a dunce.

Comment: @somecallmemike So is the question answered? Which solution worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

My best guess would be an unterminated string, most probably around the credential arguments to the PDO constructor that you've edited for your question.

I'm guessing you have something like this

```
$DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=appdb", "username", "password);
```

or similar (note the missing quote at the end).

If you use an editor with syntax highlighting (Notepad++ comes to mind), these errors will quickly become apparent.